# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' but selenium is installed

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, pip, spyder

```
import selenium
```

returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

But when I pip freeze I see:

```
selenium==4.8.2
```

Running:

- spyder 5.4.2
- python 3.8.10
- windows 11 pro

Have tried installing/uninstalling selenium with pip

Running `python -m pip install -U selenium`
returns:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

same with py instead of python

Might have something to do with environment but did not set one up after installing python, so not sure where downloaded packages are headed vs where spyder is pulling them from

Comment: Looks like you installed selenium on a different python than the one your spyder uses. Try `conda install selenium` from a conda prompt?

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install -U selenium`

Comment: python3 not recognized by cmd prompt

Comment: spyder (and vscode) were both relying on a conda environment that wasn't activated, nor was I using. deleting the anaconda3 directory from my computer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using pip3

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Comment: Using `python3 -m pip install` is better that `pip3 install` https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: using above returns "requirement already satisfied"

Comment: Tullus Dean already said that python3 is not recognized. So how it can be better than pip3?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this issue is due to your PIP and virtual environment module installation path. Your pip showing that requirement already satisfied because in python dependencies it is present but due to the path of venv it is not detecting.

you can check the PIP location using:

```
where pip
```